# Stability of Feedback Amplifiers

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback, stability

I'm kind of confused above the stability of feedback amplifiers.
Here's what I know

[image]

- \$A_f=\frac{A}{I+A\cdot\beta}\$
- \$T(j\omega)=A(j\omega)\beta(j\omega)\$
- \$A_f(j\omega)=\frac{A(j\omega)}{I+T(j\omega)}\$

In the notes, it says that 
[image]
If \$|T(j\omega)| < 1\$, then \$|A_f(j\omega)| > |A(j\omega)|\$

**I don't understand how that's true.** I tried deriving it but didn't get anywhere

[image]
\$|A_f(j\omega)| = |A(j\omega)| - |I+T(j\omega)|\$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is a logarithm sign missing. To see this, note that

$$
|A_f(j\omega)|=\left|\frac{A(j\omega)}{1+A\beta(j\omega)}\right|=\frac{|A(j\omega)|}{|1+A\beta(j\omega)|}=\frac{|A(j\omega)|}{|1+T(j\omega)|} \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
and taking the logarithm from each member of \eqref{1} you have
$$
\log |A_f(j\omega)| = \log|A(j\omega)|-\log |1+T(j\omega)|,\tag{2}\label{2}
$$
which, in my opinion is the exact form of the equation with the question mark in your notes (and is the place were the logarithm sign is missing).
Now, if 
$$
|1+T(j\omega)|<1,\tag{3}\label{3}$$ 
(and not if \$|T(j\omega)|<1\$, this is the place where a \$1\$ is missing) \$\log|1+T(j\omega)|<0\$ and then \eqref{2} implies

$$
\log |A_f(j\omega)| > \log|A(j\omega)|\iff |A_f(j\omega)| > |A(j\omega)|
$$
Now, from the point of view of the stability theory of linear systems, condition \eqref{3} means that, for a given frequency \$f\$ of the input signal \$x_i\$, the real part \$\Re[T(j\omega)]\$ of the feedback transfer function *changes its sign, becoming negative*. Thus, if \eqref{3} is verified, every change leading to an increase of the output signal \$x_o\$ (due not only to the increase of \$x_i\$, but also to parameter variation/drifts in \$A\$ and \$\beta\$) tends to be amplified instead of being attenuated, and this leads to the instability of the system.

Answer (score 0):

In your notes, there is probably an error.
In the first equation, the product \$A\cdot\beta\$ is the negative loop gain \$L(j\omega)\$.
Hence, **\$L(j\omega)=-A\cdot\beta\$**.

Note that the loop gain is the complete gain of the open loop (including the minus sign).

Now, when the loop gain is positive and >1, we have instability (criterion for instability).

That means, the **condition for instability is \$-T(j\omega)=L(j\omega)=-A\cdot\beta>1\$**

Or, with other words: **\$T(j\omega)=A\cdot\beta<(-1)\$**.

(This condition is to be compared with the expression as mentioned by you: \$|T(j\omega)|<1\$, do you see the difference?)

In this case, the denominator (and, hence, the closed-loop gain Af) becomes negative, which is a contradiction to the positive forward gain A. This indicates instability.